# Amazon AWS S3 - Allow Pre-signed Expired URL to work

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there anyway that if you gave a someone a AWS S3 Pre-signed URL with Expiration (that is now expired) that you could alter the file meta data or some setting in AWS to disregard the expiration and allow file access to that specific file (I guess it would bear some semblance to making the file public, but even with setting the file to be public, when you pass in the Expiration param, it will deny access because it has expired and I need to pass in the Pre-signed params such as AWSAccessKey/Expiration/Sig as it was opriginally.)

My issue is that an external developer was given a AWS S3 Pre-signed URL (not an AWS S3 hosted website which I think I could do a redirect) to embed in their app and for the older versions of that app that are out in the wild, the app can't retrieve the content from S3 because the url expired. We are no longer doing it this way, but for the older versions that are still out there, is there anyway we can make an expired url work again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround that will allow an expired, pre-signed URL to be used.

Making the object public does not help, because if credentials are presented, they are checked for validity before the object's permissions are checked against the credentials.

The first step of validating the signature is checking either `Expires` or `X-Amz-Expires` delta from `X-Amz-Date`, depending on the signature algorithm, to see whether the URL is expired.

This is done before the credentials are checked for validity *or even existence* -- so an expired URL with a completely fictitious set of credentials and/or an invalid signature **will still rejected as expired** based on the expiration time, alone.

Changing the expiration time does not help, because signed URLs are immune to tampering (technically speaking, it's computationally infeasible) -- so changing the expiration time into the future will cause the signature to become invalid, since the expiration timestamps are part of the inputs to the signing algorithm.

This can't be done.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the detailed reply. I assumed that to be true too before even posting the question, but just wanted to make sure that there is no way to override that on files (like having a boolean meta tag key/val on a file that sets that authentication to not be used, where the check would be on the file to see if that is present, and if flagged to false by default, then checks those params.) Noting here on my reply more details from another post concerning authentication: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113210/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expiration-time-in-signed-s3-urls

Comment: @user1178516 right -- there is no override possible at the object level, because it appears that the expired signature is rejected before the service even gets to the point of checking whether the object in question even exists.  You noticed, I assume, that I was also the author of the accepted answer on the other question you cited.

Comment: Hi Michael, yep, I noticed, but couldn't comment on that since I ran out of characters, but your reply there was also very detailed and helpful, thanks again for your help!